# Adding column to ather dataframe in R

Tags: r

It must be somewhere already solved, but I cannot find it. So, please:

df1 :

```
X Y ID
1 2 22
4 6 23
. . .
```

df2 :

```
B A ID
3 4 22
4 3 23
. . .
```

I want new df:

```
X Y ID A
1 2 22 4
4 6 23 3
. . .
```

df1 and df2 has a different length. The length of df shold be the same as length of df1.

Could somebody help me or send me a link? merge, left_join do not work..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match` to *add column `A` from `df2` to `df1` and **keep** the length of `df1`*.

```
df1$A  <- df2$A[match(df1$ID, df2$ID)]
df1
#  X Y ID A
#1 1 2 22 4
#2 4 6 23 3
```

Or using `merge`

```
merge(df1, df2[c("ID","A")], all.x=TRUE)
#  ID X Y A
#1 22 1 2 4
#2 23 4 6 3
```

In case you have more than one row per `ID` in `df2` use in addition `aggregate`.

```
merge(df1, aggregate(A ~ ID, df2, head, n=1), all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: Liked your answer (+1), but I'm wondering why `left_join()` or `merge()` don't work, and this yes, any idea (sincere question)?

Comment: @s_t `merge` will work, but only when the is one row per ID in df2. I updated the answer also for `merge`.

Comment: ah now I've understood, in OP example, ids are unique. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- If you **need to take care of matching**, then you can use `merge()` like

```
df <- merge(df1,subset(df2,select = -1),by= "ID")
```

such that

```
> df
  ID X Y A
1 22 1 2 4
2 23 4 6 3
```

or using `match()`

```
df <- df1 <- within(df1, A <- df2$A[match(ID,df2$ID)])
```

such that

```
> df
  X Y ID A
1 1 2 22 4
2 4 6 23 3
```

- If you **do not need to consider the matching issue**, then the following can make it

```
df <- cbind(df1,rev(df2[1:nrow(df1),])[2])
```

such that

```
> df
  X Y ID A
1 1 2 22 4
2 4 6 23 3
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "X Y ID
1 2 22
4 6 23",header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text = "B A ID
3 4 22
4 3 23
7  8  9",header = T)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it returns error: Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Comment: I think it should be pointed out that this solution ignores the matching between ids, simply put one table near (a part of) the other. Dunno if a kind of sort is needed.

Comment: @s_t yes, you are right, but I am not sure if the matching issue should be dealt with in OP's case just from the example, and I edited my answers